# How to generate valid bearer authorization token for google calendar

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Usually, when I need to get authorization token, In the browser I folow the link `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&client_id=myclientid`. and copy the code from the redirected link. Then, I'll make curl request `curl -d "code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&grant_type=AUTH_CODE" -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` And authorization token returned in response. Whith this token I can successfully create events in Google Calendar by POST requests.

How to get authorization token automatically? I create simple code in Java to do this, But the resulting token cannot create an event in the calendar, although, after the post request, JSON is returned about the successful creation of an event that actually does not exist
Java code to generate token:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        File credentialsFile = new File("/service.json");

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsFile))
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"));

        credential.refreshToken();

        String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();

        System.out.println("Bearer Token: " + accessToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cant the code you have now create an event?   Where is the code creating the event?

Comment: This code only getting token, code with post request to create event is another part of program, which working correctly, I checked it out with hand-generated token. The question is how to generate valid token to create events, because code presented above, generate invalid token, but when I try to create event, program return positive response, but in a fact, event not created